# How Can I Remove or Add Product Grid in WordPress Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently taking over someone else's site and can't figure out how to turn on and off the woocommerce product masonry that is shown here (scroll down the page): https://pickagifts.com/product/premium-gift-collection/

When I Inspect Element on the page, deleting the following will remove the grid:

`div class="grid" style="position: relative; height: 19729.5px;"`

However, I am not sure how to remove the grid from the actual page permanently.

After Inspecting Element is there a key indicator that will tell me where this code has been placed?

An example of the site that doesn't include the woocommerce masonry grid is: 
https://pickagifts.com/product/legacy-gift-collection/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's the `single-product.php` template which calls the `content-single-product.php` template. Look in your `theme > woocommerce` folder if there is one and find if that exists. If not, then it's most likely a plugin you need to disable. If those files exist in the `woocommerce` folder in your theme, that's where you should start. Since most of this is all custom, that's about all we can help you with without seeing code.

Comment: thanks this was helpful and I was able to find it!